# Including extension when using Application.GetSaveAsFilename()

Tags: excel, vba

I am using `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` in VBA to implement my own custom Save As function.  It works when I do this:

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename("defaultname")
```

The `File name` field says *defaultname*.  However, the expected .xlsx extension doesn't show in the dialog box.  Okay, so I'll just add it like this, right?

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename("defaultname.xlsx")
```

When I do that, the `File name` field is blank.  Apparently, Excel doesn't like the `.` because when I do this...

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename("defaultnamexlsx")
```

...it shows *defaultnamexlsx* in the `File name` field, though this is obviously not the format I am looking for.

Do I have to do something special to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it a *filter* and it will append automagically:

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename("defaultname", "Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
```

Comment: See the article on the [Application.GetSaveAsFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195734.aspx) for complete information

Comment: Love magic strings.  It works as expected.  I was hoping to be able to use the `XlFileFormat` enum, but it apparently doesn't work.  Thx.  Edit:  Also, I was really hoping to get the same behavior as the traditional Save As dialog where xlsx is the default and you can see all others.  Any way to duplicate that behavior?

Comment: You can have multiple filters: `Application.GetSaveAsFilename("defaultname", "Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx, All Files (*.*), *.*") `

Comment: @AlexK., yes, but `*.*` doesn't mean show all types, but show the filter that specifies all types.  In order for all types to display like the traditional Save As dialog, it looks like you'd literally have to hardcode every single filter.  I want this macro to be dynamic across multiple versions of Excel, so this runs the risk of not behaving properly in the event of an Excel upgrade.